# Tex4ht, biblatex and biber: what is proper processing?

Tags: biblatex, biber, tex4ht

How to run `htlatex` with biblatex bibliography included? That's the simplest example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{libr.bib}
\begin{document}

Text.\cite{dickens1881great}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I run in that way:

```
latex main
biber main
htlatex main
```

At the last stage `htlatex` asks about "Undefined control sequence":

```
\blx@begunit ...penalty \@M \hskip -\blx@unitmark 
                                              \relax \hskip \blx@unitmar...
l.7 Text.\cite{dickens1881great}
```

And there's a lot of such errors in log file, but htlatex allows to skip them. Also, the html are not so good. Lack of punctuation, formatting:

```
<p class="noindent" ><a 
 id="X0-dickens1881great"></a>C.  Dickens<span 
class="cmti-10">Great Expectations</span>Penguin  English  librarypt.  1Dent1881<span 
class="cmcsc-10"><span 
class="small-caps">u</span><span 
class="small-caps">r</span><span 
class="small-caps">l</span></span>:
    <a 
href="http://books.google.com/books?id=fhUXAAAAYAAJ" class="url" ><span 
class="cmtt-10">http://books.google.com/books?id=fhUXAAAAYAAJ</span></a>.
```

Is it the best result possible or I did something wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The biblatex adaption of tex4ht is not up-to-date. It relies on a command which no longer exists. Try

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\blx@unitmark{23sp} 
\makeatother
```