# biblatex & TeX4HT: citations in footnotes = missing \begin{document}

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, citing, html, tex4ht

the following code, which I'm trying to run through `TeX4HT` and `biber` in order to create an .odt file, results in a »missing \begin{document}« error, pointing to the aux file. Something about the citation in the footnote seems to cause trouble. No trouble occurs when

- I'm creating a pdf using ordinary `pdflatex` or `lualatex,` or
- [which is the most interesting part] a `biblatex` style *other than ›authoryear‹, like ›numeric‹,* or
- I remove the citation from the footnote

Unfortunately, I can't do without any of these three in this case, so I'd appreciate any thoughts on this issue. Thanks a lot! It might have to do with the biblatex adaption of tex4ht, so maybe what'S required here is a manual definition of a missing command, similar to what Ulrike [replied](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27290/7993) to a different but related question.

PS: same problem occurs with \footcite{BoS99}; it also occurs when creating an .html rather than an .odt (option `xhlatex`).

PPS: I'm using
mk4ht oolatex [filename]
biber [filename]
mk4ht oolatex [filename]

```
\begin{filecontents}{testbib.bib}
@BOOK{BoS99,
  author = {Bowker, Geoffrey and Star, Susan Leigh},
  year = {1999},
  title = {Sorting Things Out: Classification and its Consequences},
  address = {Cambridge, MA},
  publisher = {MIT Press}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\bibliography{testbib.bib}
\begin{document}
hat einer und gemacht zu werden%
\footnote{um von Buch wollen \cite{BoS99}}
\end{document}
```

---

**error message:**

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document} in `'.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.3 \abx@aux@fnpage{1}{1}
```

---

**contents of the aux file:**

```
\relax
\ifx\rEfLiNK\UnDef\gdef \rEfLiNK#1#2{#2}\fi
\abx@aux@fnpage{1}{1}
```

Comment: With a (mostly, i think) up to date set of packages, I have no problems with your test file.  (But run `mk4ht` *after* you have done the normal `latex, biber, latex` run.)  Relevant files: `biblatex.sty    2011/11/13 v1.7`, `biber version: 0.9.9`, and the `tex4ht` release from [CTAN](http://tug.org/tex4ht/).  You can use the `\listfiles` command in your preamble to check which versions you are using.

Comment: I keep my TeXLive up-to-date on a weekly basis, and wouldn't even think about posting a question without an additional check for updates :)
`biblatex.sty    2011/11/13 v1.7`|
`biber version: 0.9.9`|
`tex4ht.sty      2008-10-27-17:23`|
`t4ht.c (2010-12-16-08:47 kpathsea)`

I tried the workaround you suggested, `latex biber latex mk4ht` instead of `mk4ht biber mk4ht`. The problem persists, the only difference is that there's no error message in the first of the three runs invoked by the last mk4ht -- probably because that first run finds a correct aux file produced by the preceding `latex` run.

Comment: Well that is strange because I ran your file just fine with the same set of files (although AFAIK I do not have a `t4ht.c` file on my system..?).  Hopefully someone else can replicate and solve your problem.

Comment: `t4ht.c (2010-12-16-08:47 kpathsea)` is simply what shows up when I run `tex4ht` without any options or wrappers...

Comment: Hmm, I get `tex4ht.c (2009-01-31-07:33 kpathsea)`, but not `t4ht.c`.  That might be worth investigating further.

Comment: did some further research; fond out a couple of new (to me) things about tex4ht. Its author passed away in 2009, so the parts of TeX4HT that take care of its interaction with biblatex could not evolve along with biblatex, so the two grew increasingly incompatible. Karl Berry et al. have taken over maintenance of texht. Some parts of it have been updated already. There's a new biblatex.4ht for example (included in my TeXLive 2012), but it still seems to be missing a few things to interact correctly with the last biblatex version Philipp Lehman released before his disappearance last fall.

Comment: [this](http://tug.org/pipermail/tex4ht/2012q2/000539.html) discussion I found particularly enlightening, and with a few detours it solved my problem. Someone [mentions](http://tug.org/pipermail/tex4ht/2012q2/000551.html) an unofficial update of biblatex.4ht by one Daniel von Wachter. Among other things, it contains one line that fixes my problem: `\let\abx@aux@fnpage\@gobbletwo.` I've now taken over that line into my custom .sty file, leaving the biblatex.4ht from TeXLive 2012 untouched. That file's version, by the way, is `2011-09-18-16:07.` Not sure if I can consider the issue »solved«, tho.

Comment: Post it as an answer (or at least a partial one) so we can delete the comments and make it easier for others to find out what got you going again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, some further research turned up a few interesting things about `tex4ht` and its relationship with `biblatex,` plus a provisional fix for my problem. In a nutshell: the author of tex4ht passed away in 2009, and even though Karl Berry et al. took over maintenance, it is not yet fully compatible with the biblatex versions released since then. But they're working on it, and TeXLive 2012 already contains a more up-to-date version of `biblatex.4ht` (the file that's in charge of the interaction between the two). However, even that version doesn't contain what's necessary for my example to work. I found what I need, though, in an unofficial, anonymous version of biblatex.4ht mentioned [here](http://tug.org/pipermail/tex4ht/2012q2/000552.html).

So what follows is basically a personal bugfix for my specific problem -- until tex4ht has regained full compatibility with biblatex. I think I should submit the issue to tex4ht's bug [database,](https://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/bugs/?group=tex4ht) as it doesn't seem to be in there yet.

```
\begin{filecontents}{testbib.bib}
@BOOK{BoS99,
  author = {Bowker, Geoffrey and Star, Susan Leigh},
  year = {1999},
  title = {Sorting Things Out: Classification and its Consequences},
  address = {Cambridge, MA},
  publisher = {MIT Press}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\bibliography{testbib.bib}
\makeatletter                    %[!]
\let\abx@aux@fnpage\@gobbletwo   %[!]
\makeatother                     %[!]
\begin{document}
hat einer und gemacht zu werden%
\footnote{um von Buch wollen \cite{BoS99}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but my latex file had some missing references to pictures I didn't wanted in the rtf version. When I removed those it worked perfectly. So I think that the issue it may be related not to the bibliography itself but to way latex or word tackles references.