# How can I use latex2rtf with biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, latex2rtf

I would like to output a .tex file in .rtf format. Latex2rtf does the job, except that it does not support biblatex ("package/option unknown"); thus, in the rtf, the citations are replaced with "[Error: Reference source not found]". Is there a way to get latex2rtf to work with biblatex? If not, what is the easiest way to move from tex to rtf with citations intact?

Comment: Probably the only way is [tex4ht](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tex4ht) --- converting to OpenDocument and then to RTF. It works quite well with `biblatex`. Although I also would be glad to learn about other methods, since I had problems with converting math with `tex4ht`.

Comment: I've had no problems using natbib with bibtex. Just get a document that compiles and the conversion with latex2rtf works fine.

Comment: Thanks both. I will try tex4ht, which I'd not heard of. I'd rather stick with biblatex than shift over to natbib+bibtex just for this one stupid journal article.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can suggest 2 ways.

1. [tex4ht](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tex4ht) (included in Texlive and Miktex) supports `biblatex` and works quite well. It may fail with some fonts, packages, etc., so it's better to avoid too exotic ones.
2. `biblatex` has the `natbib` compatibility option. So, if you use only `natbib` commands `\citep`, `\citet`, etc., you may easily switch from `biblatex` to `bibtex` (by commenting/uncommenting few lines) and then use `latex2rtf` or other tools. This is a limited "support" of `biblatex` but it may be enough for your needs. You even may have redefinitions like `\renewcommand*{\citep}{\autocite}` and preserve some advantages of biblatex.

Comment: Thanks. Tex4ht works very well -- better than option 2. I had to add some lines toto my preamble as per this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62885/biblatex-tex4ht-citations-in-footnotes-missing-begindocument 
And I have not managed to get the outputted file to display superscript footnote markers correctly, but it's close enough.