# Conversion from latex(pdf) to rtf

Tags: biblatex, latex2rtf

I have latex2rtf installed in my mac.
I have a pdf file generated in latex format for my bibliography entries. How can I convert it to rtf?

I used something like

```
    latex2rtf -o <output_file_in_rtf_format> <latex_pdf_file>
```

It doesn't work!

Comment: pdf is not latex. If your file is really a pdf it won't work.

Comment: You can't. PDF is an irreversible format with respect to the LaTeX source. `latex2rtf` converts LaTeX source to RTF. You would probably be better off using Adobe Acrobat to export the PDF as a Word document instead.

Comment: As you should have the source bib(la)tex files you could consider the answers in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136094/how-can-i-use-latex2rtf-with-biblatex if the results are poor the other suggestions are usually bibtex2html or tex4ht then html to word. since you usually end up spending much time in word converting the format to suit RTF, I usually just copy all the document as plain text (and graphics) and using the default RTF editor (WordPad) make the format changes (font size/family/color justification) there once. It helps if we know Why? you thing RTF is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Converting pdfs to latex doesn't work that well, also converting tex to rtf has its limitations. A combination of tools might serve you better. For example

Consider using [bibtex2html](https://www.lri.fr/~filliatr/bibtex2html/) and then exporting the result to html. In addition, pandoc can render references fairly well.