# Running TeX4ht while using biblatex renders empty .html file

Tags: biblatex, tex4ht

The issue I'm facing: Running TeX4ht renders an empty document when using references with biblatex. I'm using TeXmaker 4.1 on a PepperMint 5 OS (based on Ubuntu 14.04).

The preamble of the document looks like this:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,
hyperref=true,
style=authoryear-icomp,
firstinits=true,
dashed=false,
url=false,
isbn=false,
doi=false,
maxcitenames=2,
maxbibnames=6]{biblatex}
\bibliography{literature}

\let\citep\cite
%\let\cite\footcite
%\let\citep\footcite

\usepackage{endnotes}
\let\footnote\endnote

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{setspace}

\author{Author}
\title{Political Science}
\begin{document}
Lastly, I have a conclusion (\cite{plato_republic_2005}).
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This works just fine when rendering a regular pdf, but creates an empty document in TeX4ht. The file produced is empty when opened in a browser, but does contain something when opened with GEDIT.

Message from TeX4ht:

> "htlatex"
>   "/home/dijkman/Dropbox/Studie/Challenges/TeX/presidentpaper.tex" " " "
>   " " " -interaction=nonstopmode Process exited normally

Content of the .html file (in GEDIT):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"  
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">  
<html > 
<head><title>Political Science</title> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"> 
<meta name="generator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~gurari/TeX4ht/)"> 
<meta name="originator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~gurari/TeX4ht/)"> 
<!-- html --> 
<meta name="src" content="importantpaper.tex"> 
<meta name="date" content="2015-03-23 17:24:00"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="importantpaper.css"> 
</head><body 
>
   <div class="maketitle">
```

I would be very grateful if someone could help me out with this, since it would allow me to paste the results in a Word document for comments from my supervisor (a)

PS: Relatively new to LaTeX, hope I haven't overlooked something obvious or something already explained. Furthermore, I hope to have posted enough info.

Edit: The .bib file is a biblatex export from Zotero (or BibTeX, both work for the pdf). Example from the file:

```
@incollection{keane_john_monitory_2011,
    location = {Cambridge},
    title = {Monitory Democracy?},
    pages = {212--235},
    booktitle = {The Future of Representative Democracy},
    publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
    author = {Keane, John},
    editor = {Alonso, Sonia and Keane, John and Merkel, Wolfgang},
    date = {2011}
}

@article{zurn_democracy_2011,
    title = {Democracy and representation beyond the nation state},
    pages = {258},
    journaltitle = {The future of representative democracy},
    author = {Zürn, Michael and Walter-Drop, Gregor},
    date = {2011}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  My guess is that tex4ht is too old to know about `biblatex` which is relatively new.

Comment: Ah, that would be too bad. Would you know any (newer) alternatives I could use? And thanks for the welcome, really like the site!

Comment: @Statistics `tex4ht` does have support for `biblatex`. some bugs were fixed recently, so you need to have updated TeX Live to get these fixes. did you run `biber`? you have to do it manually. could you post also the `.bib` file here?

Comment: I'll go and find out about TeX Live. I'll also try to add the .bib file. Essentially, its a biblatex export from Zotero.

Comment: By the way, I did not run biber. Did run BibTeX though (F11 on my TeXmaker)

Comment: @Statistics ah, I see, you use bibtex, it shouldn't make a difference. your example works for me, when I use a reference contained in the bib file, so update should help

Comment: I have TeXmaker 4.1 and TeX4ht 20090611-1.1build1 apparently, but I can't really find where to update either; the Update manager of peppermint does not offer a new version at least. Also a bit new to Linux unfortunately

Comment: @Statistics TeXLive bundled with Linux distributions can't be updated unfortunately. you have to install standalone TeX Live: https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html if you want updated TeX distribution

Comment: If I change your MWE so that it actually produces a citation (I used the file `biblatex-examples.bib` and cited `cicero`) and follow the advice given [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27288/35864) your document compiles just fine and gives a nice output.

Comment: If you don't run `htlatex` in `nonstopmode` do you get any errors or warnings? Please also locate your version of `biblatex.4ht` and report the version, [here](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/biblatex.4ht) is one from `2015-02-04` (the newest I could find on the web). With this newest version in a place where it is preferred to the older versions of `biblatex.4ht` that might be around on your computer, everything works very fine out of the box.

Comment: Thanks a lot all for the help! Adding the following to the preamble worked (from the solution in the link of moewe): 
`\makeatletter
\newcommand\blx@unitmark{23sp} 
\makeatother`

Comment: So the solution _was_ online after all, and can be found [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27288/tex4ht-biblatex-and-biber-what-is-proper-processing)